# Should I be using a multi-index in my dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

[image]I have a dataframe  of 60 rows and over 5000 columns.  The data is imported from a spreadsheet in the same format.  Each row is for a particular date (15 years quarterly, 15 x 4 = 60) while the columns consist of 85 different companies and 60 variables (85*60 =5100)

I unfortunately cant post the data but here is a sample of df.head() (see image)

My question is what is the best way to filter and manage the data.  Should I use muli-index in dataframe? Pivot tables or group by?

So far what I have done, which I don’t think is optimal is the following:

```
# Series a - for one company and one metric over time #

#Criteria
Ticker = df.loc[0,:]=="Company1"  
Metric = df.loc[2,:]=="Sales"
a=df.loc[:,Ticker & Metric][![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

Comment: It depends on what you ultimately want to do.  There is no right answer/method for data wrangling/analysis.

Comment: I would use indexes to label your numerical data.   You could in this case import the data in with rows [0,1] as column headers thus creating a multiindex, and column[0] as the dataframe index. Then, next depending on your task at hand you can reshape, filter, aggregate, your dataframe to do your analysis.

Comment: Thank you @scott-boston  to convert one row as a column header I would proceed as follows 

    df.columns = df.iloc[0]

but what about for the second?

Comment: On import, if you are using pd.read_csv or read_excel you could use `header` parameter with a list   `header=[0,1]' to convert the first two rows in to a multiindex column header.

Comment: Thanks. Although the data comes in transposed so I first need to do a .T to make the dates going down vs. across.